# What is the difference between a bonus and a power-up?

Tags: game-design

What is the difference between the notions of "bonus" and "power-up?"

I have in-game some objects and the player has the ability to pick up some bonuses/power-ups that allow the player to create an explosion all around. There's also an item that lets the player teleport from one place to another -- are these all power-ups?

Comment: A bonus signifies permanent change (increased abilities while wearing an item) a power up is temporary (increased abilities for a limited amount of time). Also bonuses are usually awarded while power ups are collected.

Answer (score 23):

"Bonus" is usually used to describe something that effects the score or the outcome of the game (such as a score multiplier). "Power-ups" generally refer to things that give the game extra abilities/mechanics like increased speed or power. However, whoever you are talking to will probably understand what you mean no matter which word you use.

Answer (score 11):

Personnaly, I'd see :

- a "power-up" as something that makes you more "potent"
- a "bonus" as a reward

Answer (score 7):

Genrally (and perhaps not only in games)...

- a **powerup** is an addition to what you can **do**, or ["power-ups are objects that instantly benefit or add extra abilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-up)"
- a **bonus** is an addition to what you **get** ["The word Bonus refers to extra pay due to good performance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonus)

IMHO there is no **bonus** in what you describe, but only the pickup that lets the player explode all around (as a **powerup**), where the teleport is simply a **trigger**.

E.g. in Super Mario you have the coins which are simply **pickups** and you have the mushrooms that actually give you an extra ability making the mushroom a **powerup**.
In some games you gain an extra bonus if you complete a level if you completed the level within a given time.

Answer (score 5):

From my point of view,

- "power-ups" are items/abilities that can be gathered while playing (like a super temporary shield) to help,
- whereas "bonus" is something given because you were good enough to deserve it (like a bonus stage).

But power-ups are often called bonus and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

- "power-ups" as the word suggests "pulls-up" your current "powers" ingame. Thus the effect is temporary and your powers will return to their previous default value when the power-up expired.
- A "bonus" is an addition to the things you own ingame (score, collection, powers) but it is has no time-out. (example : have a defensive bonus on a shield. the bonus won't go away unless i decide to swap it for some other bonus / if the bonus can expire after some time it's a power-up ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

bonuses give you extra points/currency

power-ups give you extra abilities which you can use to earn points/currency more efficiently